# Change the chart bar color on select using charts_flutter in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bar-chart, flutter-dependencies

> I want to change or highlight the bar when user click on it also how to round this bar at bottom. I try to make but I can not make it according to it kindly help me to build it.
> my some code is

```
charts.TimeSeriesChart(
        widget.seriesList,
        animate: widget.animate,
        primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
            renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
              tickLengthPx: 0,
            ),
            showAxisLine: false),
        dateTimeFactory: charts.LocalDateTimeFactory(),
        domainAxis: charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
          renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
            tickLengthPx: 0,
          ),
          showAxisLine: false,
          tickFormatterSpec: charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec(
            month: charts.TimeFormatterSpec(
              format: 'EEE',
              transitionFormat: 'EEE',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        defaultRenderer: charts.BarRendererConfig(
            cornerStrategy: charts.ConstCornerStrategy(30)),
        defaultInteractions: true,
        selectionModels: [
          SelectionModelConfig(
              type: SelectionModelType.info,
              changedListener: (SelectionModel model) {
                if (model.hasDatumSelection)
                  pointerValue = model.selectedSeries[0]
                      .measureFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index)
                      .toString();
              })
        ],
        behaviors: [
          new LinePointHighlighter(
              symbolRenderer:
                  CustomCircleSymbolRenderer(text: textSelected)),
        ],
      )
```

> my code result this

[image]

> and I want this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[disclaimer - only changing the chart bar color on select using charts_flutter. No solution for the rounding of the bars at the bottom]

After desperately searching for a way to achieve this, I've finally found, how I can edit the color of a selected bar.
As charts_flutter uses charts_common, it's been a bit hard to find the right classes to extend and override, but here goes:

- first off: add the current version of https://pub.dev/packages/charts_common: `charts_common: ^0.12.0`
- write your own Domain Highlighter (this is the charts_flutter highlighter)

```
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart';

class CustomDomainHighlighter<D> extends DomainHighlighter<D> {

  @override
  common.DomainHighlighter<D> createCommonBehavior() =>
      CustomCommonDomainHighlighter<D>(selectionModelType);
}
```

- write the Common Domain Highlighter -> this is where the color for the highlighted bar is set:

```
import 'package:charts_common/common.dart' as common;

class CustomCommonDomainHighlighter<D> extends common.DomainHighlighter<D> {
  late final common.SelectionModelType selectionModelType;

  late common.BaseChart<D> _chart;

  late common.LifecycleListener<D> _lifecycleListener;

  CustomCommonDomainHighlighter([this.selectionModelType = common.SelectionModelType.info]) {
    _lifecycleListener =
        common.LifecycleListener<D>(onPostprocess: _updateColorFunctions);
  }

  void _selectionChanged(SelectionModel<D> selectionModel) {
    _chart.redraw(skipLayout: true, skipAnimation: true);
  }

  void _updateColorFunctions(List<common.MutableSeries<D>> seriesList) {
    SelectionModel<D> selectionModel =
    _chart.getSelectionModel(selectionModelType);
    if(selectionModel.hasAnySelection) {
      seriesList.forEach((common.MutableSeries<D> series) {
        final origColorFn = series.colorFn;

        if (origColorFn != null) {
          series.colorFn = (int? index) {
            final origColor = origColorFn(index);
            if (selectionModel.isDatumSelected(series, index)) {
              return origColor;
            } else {
              return Color(r: origColor.r, g: origColor.g, b: origColor.b, a: 128);
            }
          };
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void attachTo(common.BaseChart<D> chart) {
    _chart = chart;
    chart.addLifecycleListener(_lifecycleListener);
    chart
        .getSelectionModel(selectionModelType)
        .addSelectionChangedListener(_selectionChanged);
  }

  @override
  void removeFrom(common.BaseChart<D> chart) {
    chart
        .getSelectionModel(selectionModelType)
        .removeSelectionChangedListener(_selectionChanged);
    chart.removeLifecycleListener(_lifecycleListener);
  }

  @override
  String get role => 'domainHighlight-$selectionModelType';
}
```

- so you don't overlook it, the color is set here: `_updateColorFunctions`. I've customized it, so everything looks highlighted, if nothing's selected, and when the user selects a bar, all the other bars keep the color, but with half the alpha (opacity of 0.5).
- To use this highlighter, add it to the chart behaviours:

```
charts.BarChart(
        seriesList,
        animate: true,
        behaviors: [
           CustomDomainHighlighter(),
           charts.SelectNearest(eventTrigger: charts.SelectionTrigger.tapAndDrag)
    ];
```